# Dwarfes hauling from Minecart quantum stockpile to receiver Stockpile - Circular stockpiles

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I've been trying to work out minecart routes which should deliver the carpenter and still. Also another one should bring food & drinks to the dining room below. However, things work out disastrously. What happens is that dwarfes pick up items from the resulting quantum stockpiles and carry back to the minecart receiver. Is there a way to prevent item hauling for the quantum stockpiles?

Save is uploaded here: http://www.file-upload.net/download-10929406/circular-stockpiles.zip.html

Anyone might be knowing what is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Please note that when you are publishing a save, you should say what version it uses. I am going to try looking into it with the current version.

Comment: Well there are a number of things wrong, but I think I covered them all in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

So your problem is that you have, as you may have guessed, a small error in the construction of your [quantum stockpile.](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Quantum_stockpile#The_Minecart_Stop) In you current setup you have a minecart and stop next to a single stockpile from which it takes goods and into which it dumps goods. The proper arrangement uses **2 different** stockpiles per quantum stockpile. They must be defined separately. One of them collects goods to be put into the stockpile and the other is dumped into and is only present to control the use of the goods after they have been dumped.

I will reproduce the diagram from the wiki and explain the parts.

```
III
 S
 O
```

The I area is a stockpile, call it stone stockpile #12 (for example). Its purpose is to gather items for the quantum stockpile.

The S is the track stop which dumps into stockpile O(south in this case). It is set to take from the I stockpile (stone stockpile #12).

The O is the output stockpile, call it stone stockpile #17. Its purpose is to store the contents of the stockpile group. Any hauling routes that take from the quantum stockpile should take from O(stone stockpile #17). O must not show up in the hauling route that defines the quantum stockpile. O must accept anything that will be put into the stockpile otherwise it won't hold on to them.

The S and O stockpiles **must** be different stockpiles. They should have different names and have been defined separately (just not part of the same rectangle you don't have to leave the stockpile tool between definitions, although you may).

The way it works is that dwarves see empty spaces in stockpile I and bring the items to it. Then another dwarf sees that there is a hauling route to put things from stockpile I into the minecart at S, so they do. The minecart immediately dumps anything put into it south, which, just by coincidence (read in a faux innocent tone), happens to be a stockpile that accepts those types of items. Since those items are in a stockpile now, and nothing takes from that stockpile, they will be left there until a dwarf needs one. This has also left an open space in stockpile I, which restarts the process.

Your current setup however looks like this:

```
  I
SII
  I
```

Where I is your stockpile, and S is your minecart stop which dumps into I and also takes from it. I this situation the following happens. A dwarf sees something in stockpile I which is linked to stop S. So he takes that thing and puts it into the minecart, as he is supposed to. The minecart then immediately dumps it back out into the same stockpile and the pattern repeats, doing basically nothing.

To change your current setup into a quantum stockpile that will do what you want, you can do the following:

Remove the statues near the track stops so that you have space. Where the statues were create another stockpile that accepts the proper sort of goods.
Go into the hauling menu and change the route for the stop so that it takes from this new stockpile and not the old one.

Since the [minecart stops](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Minecart#Track_Stops) weren't built to dump you will also need to rebuild them. Just deconstruct the track stop and then when placing it use the 'd' key to change the direction it dumps until it will dump into your new O stockpile.

Finally, the wiki notes in the second to last paragraph of the quantum stockpile section that they are not good for food and drink (or anything stored in barrels or bins.) So be sure to set the bin and barrel numbers to zero for your quantum stockpiles.

That should be sufficient. There are things you can do to clean up the route, like removing the push when full instruction, but they are not necessary to getting the quantum stockpile working.

The minecart based quantum stockpile works just like a normal stockpile, except that it takes advantage of the fact that minecarts will dump things in places that dwarves wouldn't. So you can imagine a minecart based hauling route that dumps into a large stockpile. In fact this may well be how they were first discovered. Someone set up such a system and then noticed that one square had a huge amount of stuff on it.

Hopefully this is somewhat useful.

Comment: A neat trick with quantum stockpiles? Nothing that doesn't go into the feeder or input stockpile will go any further, so you can set the hauling route and the storage stockpile to accept everything (so long as the storage stockpile has an object on every square already).

Comment: Note that I discovered a couple other problems after I wrote that first paragraph. I edited them (and solutions) in to later paragraphs. Well, there isn't really a solution to the problem that quantum stockpiles don't work right for drinks.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at your save game, but I think I know where you went wrong.
I'll describe the smallest (that I know of) setup for building a quantum stockpile. `NO MINECART TRACKS NEEDED`.

- You need 2 stockpiles, the 1<sup>st</sup> one feeds items to the 2<sup>nd</sup> stockpile. The 2<sup>nd</sup> stockpile will be your quantum stockpile, and needs to be only 1x1 square of stockpile. Ideally, put these two stockpiles next to each other, with only 1 square between them, which is where your track stop will come (more on that later)...
- Of course, your 1<sup>st</sup> stockpile will accept a number of things. Edit these to your liking, from the main menu press <kbd>q</kbd>, put the cursor over your stockpile, then press <kbd>s</kbd> to tweak the stockpile's settings.
- The 2<sup>nd</sup> stockpile (q-pile) will also need to accept a number of things. This collection needs to be partly or completely the same as the things that go into your 1<sup>st</sup> stockpile. This is IMPORTANT, because a q-pile that gets mudstone dumped into it, but doesn't accept those, will be an endless source of hauling jobs for your <strike>drunks</strike> dwarfs.
- Right next to your q-pile, you need to build a track stop <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. As mentioned before, ideally put this track stop between your 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> stockpiles.
- Design it, so it dumps everything in the direction of your q-pile, but don't worry about it, you can still redefine this when the damn thing finally gets built inbetween meetings, sleep, rest, parties, breaks, fighting demonstrations and stockpiling owned items 40 floors down. Usually, I build this track stop right inbetween the 2 stockpiles, to minimise hauling distances.
- Also set the friction to `Highest`.
- Now define a new hauling route <kbd>h</kbd>, new route <kbd>r</kbd>, name it <kbd>n</kbd> something descriptive.
- Move the cursor on top of the track stop, and define a new ROUTE stop <kbd>s</kbd> here. Note that a route stop (which is a spot on a hauling route) is not the same thing as a track stop (which is a building).
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> to define this stop. Delete the default stop conditions <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>. Then move your cursor over the 1<sup>st</sup> stockpile and press <kbd>s</kbd> to indicate that this stop will take stuff from it.
- <kbd>v</kbd> to designate a minecart to this route stop.
- One thing left to do: press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once more to define what items should be loaded into the minecart. IMPORTANT: I repeat, if this route stop dumps stuff on the q-pile that does not accept this item type, these items will be removed from the q-pile (and will probably be moved back to the 1<sup>st</sup> stockpile).

This procedure might seem a little complex, but it really isn't. Once you get a grip on it, you'll be quantum dumping everything from huge mineral deposits to clown body parts.

Note that no minecart tracks are needed. The minecart will never fill up, so you will not be waiting for your legendary procrastinators to launch it to its destination. Once placed, the minecart will immediately dump anything that gets placed into it to the q-pile.

Several of these trackstops can be used to effectively split a large stockpile with many different item types, into several q-piles with very specific item types, reducing your stockpile surface and putting needed resources close to your workshops.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you don't define the items which a hauling route should take, every item-type of the seeder stockpile will be loaded into you minecart, and as a result get dumped into your q-pile.

Comment: One other thing I recently discovered, it is not really necessary to define a stockpile link for your hauling stop. You won't be able to empty a stockpile like this, but desired items that are NOT in an appropriate stockpile anywhere in your fort, will be loaded into your minecart.